# How to disable CORS completelly in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, cors, ktor

I want to do a very basic thing with Ktor: add the following configuration:

```
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
```

I went through [the CORS documentation of Ktor](https://ktor.io/docs/cors.html) and I have not found how to achieve it.

The following configuration works with GET requests, but POST request fail.

```
install(CORS) {
    anyHost()
}
```

Exploring the APIs through my IDE didn't help much.

**Q:** How to disable CORS completelly in Ktor?

Comment: You may try to list all methods and use `allowHeadersPrefixed("")`

Comment: Thanks @dan1st. Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: The [doc](https://ktor.io/docs/cors.html#methods) says that *By default, the CORS plugin allows the GET, POST and HEAD HTTP methods*. So ideally that should work for POST too. But you can try adding `method(HttpMethod.Post)` to it.

Comment: I just tried with only `install(CORS) { anyHost() }` and it works for POST too. Could you please elaborate on how you're testing the POST request and how it's failing?

Comment: The issue was content type in my case. In my code, POST requests specify content type, but GET requests don't. That's why POST didn't work. But the question is still relevant, I want to **completely** disable CORS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`anyHost()` is equivalent for `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`

`allowHeaders { true }` is equivalent for `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"`

`HttpMethod.DefaultMethods.forEach { method(it) }` is equivalent for `"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"`